# Ubuntu, can not connect to MongoDB from Node.js (installed with nvm) and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I have perfectly working code for mongoose which works well on Windows, Mac OS, and have been tested many times. Just some time ago i have installed ubuntu and set everything up, but after installing node and running the same code  i am not able to connect to data base and i am getting error with timeout in connection. This behavior is only on Linux Ubuntu.

Also to test i have installed Mongo Compass and it works well too. The only thing which does not work is connection from Node.js Mongoose to external Mongo database.

Is there any kinda special configurations for Ubuntu to make it work?

Comment: Can you share some code that you used? Ubuntu does not need anything specific, btw.

Comment: There is no much i am just trying to connect to shards in amazon with: ```mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pazsword@[host:port],[host:port]...')```